# Unable to publish the Azure function from vscode to Azure #3827

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

Trying to publish function as below code:

`func azure functionapp publish funclogicabcd`

While executing above command, Following error occurs:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools does not support this deployment path. Please configure the app to deploy from a remote package using the steps here: https://aka.ms/deployfromurl
```

Comment: Are you publishing function to Linux functionapp and also do you have `AzureWebJobStorage` setting in `local.settings.json`?

Answer (score 2):

**Follow below steps to publish function to Azure function app:**

- Make sure you have below settings in `FunctionApp=>Settings=>Configuration=>General Settings`:

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connection_string>"
"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" = "<your_zipfile_url>"
```

- Check if you have installed ***Azure function core tools***:

`npm -g list azure-functions-core-tools`

[image]

Try creating new function app:

```
func init
```

[image]

```
func new
```

[image]

```
func start
```

[image]

```
func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name>
```

[image]
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**References:**

1. [GitHub Issue1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3376)
2. [GitHub Issue2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3657)